# A clarification on this Fourier series

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

This is a follow-up from this thread:

[Compute the Fourier series for $f(x)=x$ over the interval $-\pi\leq x \leq\pi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3132796/compute-the-fourier-series-for-fx-x-over-the-interval-pi-leq-x-leq-pi)

$$b_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\sin(nx)dx=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi x\sin(nx)dx$$.

This integral for evaluation is $${ -\dfrac{x\cos(nx)}{n}+\dfrac{\sin(nx)}{n^2}} \Big|_\pi^\pi$$

For $$x=\pm\pi, \dfrac{\sin(nx)}{n^2}=0$$ But what about coefficient $-\dfrac{2}{n}\cos(nx)=-\dfrac{2}{n}(-1)^{n+1}$? How do you obtain this coefficient from the integral? To be more precise, I am stuck at the number $2$ there.

I am just tracing steps from here: http://www.sosmath.com/fourier/fourier1/fourier1.html

Answer (score 1):

When you're doing Fourier series, it's good to know that $\sin n\pi = 0$ and $\cos n\pi = (-1)^n$ when $n$ is an integer.  So you have

$$\left.-\frac{x\cos nx}{n}\right|_{-\pi}^{\pi} =
-\frac{\pi\cos n\pi}{n} -\left(- \frac{-\pi\cos(-n\pi)}{n}\right)$$

$$= -\frac{\pi(-1)^n}{n} - \frac{\pi(-1)^{-n}}{n} = -2\frac{\pi(-1)^n}{n} = \frac{2\pi(-1)^{n+1}}{n}.$$

(I think you have a minus sign error in your final coefficient.)

Comment: Why do you have $2\pi$?, the website I presented states that the coefficient is $\dfrac{2}{n}(-1)^{n+1}$.

Comment: In this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xEr3GuVVkfg&t=167s the integral is represented as $\dfrac{2\sin(\pi n)-2\pi n\cos(\pi n)}{n^{2}\pi}$, I wonder why?

Comment: I'm just doing the integral.  When you multiply by the $1/\pi$ on the outside, the $\pi$ will go away.   For you second comment, often, when dealing with an even function, folks will replace $\int_{-L}^L$ with  $2\int_0^L$ so you get an automatic $2$.